# Pass prop from top level of react project from file using render from "react-dom"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

I'm currently working on a personal project just to get a bit better using react.

I use react-router for navigation. My index.js file has the following

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import TukTukTours from "./components/TukTukTours";
import BycicleTours from "./components/BicycleTours";
import WalkingTours from "./components/WalkingTours";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(
  <BrowserRouter>
     <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
        <Route path='tuktuktours' element={<TukTukTours/>}/>
        <Route path='bycicletours' element={<BycicleTours/>}/>
        <Route path='walkingtours' element={<WalkingTours/>}/>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement
);
```

The App component is what loads the main page basically, I have a nav bar there which has a select box that changes between two languages. Once the user changes all the text in the page changes from one language to another. I want the same to happen on my three other pages (Routes above).

For that I want to pass down a state variable to App, WalkingTours, BycicleTours and TukTukTours to dynamically change the content of the pages.

The way I have index.js structured it doesn't look like I can use `useState` hook to achieve what I want. Something similar to the below;

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import TukTukTours from "./components/TukTukTours";
import BycicleTours from "./components/BicycleTours";
import WalkingTours from "./components/WalkingTours";
import { useState } from "react";

const [language, setLanguage] = useState("GB");

const changeLanguage = (language) => setLang(language);
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(
  <BrowserRouter>
     <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App language={language} setLang={changeLanguage} />} />
        <Route path='tuktuktours' element={<TukTukTours language={language}/>}/>
        <Route path='bycicletours' element={<BycicleTours language={language}/>}/>
        <Route path='walkingtours' element={<WalkingTours language={language}/>}/>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement
);
```

I know the above is not valid because I can't use hooks outside react function components or custom hook functions.

What would be the best way to achieve what I have above?

Many thanks

Comment: This is subjective, but: if the state is shared by all children of `App`, put the state in `App` and pass its value and setter as props to the children (including the nav bar).

Comment: That is what I currently have yes, the only issue is that WalkingTours, TukTukTours and BycicleTour are not children of app. They are "different" pages

Comment: In a conventional React app, `App` is the parent to the other components. It's where you'll find stuff like state that's shared between children.

Comment: I think your comment just made my head click, I think my structure is completely wrong. I can have the routes established on index.js but my components, whether those are different pages or not, loading under App right?

Comment: The version of React Router you're using matters. Check out the docs for your version; they each have excellent examples. But yes, `App` is typically the parent to all components and that's where your shared language logic could live.